# Transferring data using ultrasound

Tags: iphone, android, audio, signal-processing, data-transfer

[Yamaha InfoSound](http://www.engadget.com/2010/12/20/yamaha-infosound-prototype-talks-to-your-phone-as-you-zone-out-d/) and [ShopKick application](http://shopkick.com/) use technologies that allow to **transfer data using ultrasound**. That is playing an inaudible signal (>18kHz) that can be picked up by modern mobile phones (iOS, Android).

**What is the approach used in such technologies? What kind of modulation they use?**

Comment: A question about modulation schemes might belong on the electronics.stackexchange forum.  After you determine the modulation scheme, a question about the audio DSP code required for iPhone or Android to modulate or demodulate some protocol might be more appropriate for here.

Comment: There is at least 1 virus that uses ultrasound as a mean to propagate itself. Pretty scary http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/10/meet-badbios-the-mysterious-mac-and-pc-malware-that-jumps-airgaps/

Comment: @alexey - do u find solution for data transfer via ultrasound?

Comment: @alexey how does the shopkick use this ?? what is the usecase ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see several problems with this approach. First, 18kHz is *not* inaudible. Many people cannot hear it, especially as they age, but I know I certainly can (I do regular hearing tests, work-related). Also, most phones have different low-pass filters on their [A/D converters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AD-converter), and many devices, especially older Android ones (I've personally seen that happen), filter everything below 16 kHz or so. Your app therefore is not guaranteed to work on any hardware. The iPhone should probably be able to do it.

In terms of modulation, it could be anything really, but I would definitely rule out AM. Sound has next to zero robustness when it comes to volume. If I were to implement something like that, I would go with [FSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying). I would think that [PSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying) would fail due to acoustic reflections and such. The difficulty is that you're working with non-robust energy transfer within a very narrow bandwidth. I certainly do not doubt that it can be achieved, but I don't see something like this proving reliable. Just IMHO, that is.

**Update**: Now that i think about it, a plain on-off would work with a single tone if you're not transferring any data, just some short signals.

Comment: Can you refer any (re)source where FSK used to transfer data using ultrasound?

Answer (score 3):

Can't say for Yamaha InfoSound and ShopKick, but what we used in our project was a variation of frequency modulation: the frequency of the carrier is modulated by a digital binary signal, where 0 and 1 correspond to 17 kHz and 18 kHz respectively. As for demodulator, we tried heterodyne. More details you could find here: http://rnd.azoft.com/mobile-app-transering-data-using-ultrasound/

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special in being ultrasound, the principle is the same as data transmission through a modem, so any [digital modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation#Digital_modulation_methods) is -in principle- feasible. You only have a specific frequency band (above 18khz) and some practical requisites (the medium is very unreliable, I guess) that suggest to use a simple-robust scheme with low-bit rate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how they do it but this is how I do it:

If it is a string then make sure it's not a long one (the longer the higher is the error probability ). Lets assume we're working with the vital part of the ASCII code, namely up to character number 127, then all you need is 7 bits per character. Transform this character into bits and modulate those bits using QFSK (there are several modulations to choose from, frequency shift based ones have turned out to be the most robust I've tried from the conventional ones... I've created my own modulation scheme for this use case). Select the carrier frequencies as 18.5,19,19.5, and 20 kHz (if you want to be mathematically strict in your design, select frequency values that assure you both orthogonality and phase continuity at symbol transitions, if you can't, a good workaround to avoid abrupt symbols transitions is to multiply your symbols by a window of the same size, eg. a Gaussian or Bartlet ). In my experience you can move this values in the range from 17.5 to 20.5 kHz (if you go lower it will start to bother people using your app, if you go higher the average type microphone frequency response will attenuate your transmission and induce unwanted errors).

On the receiver side implement a correlation or matched filter receiver (an FFT receiver works as well, specially a zero padded one but it might be a little bit slower, I wouldn't recommend Goertzel because frequency shift due to Doppler effect or speaker-microphone non-linearities could affect your reception). Once you have received the bit stream make characters with them and you will recover your message

If you face too many broadcasting errors, try selecting a higher amount of samples per symbol or band-pass filtering each frequency value before giving them to the demodulator, using an error correction code such as BCH or Reed Solomon is sometimes the only way to assure an error free communication.

One topic everybody always forgets to talk about is synchronization (to know on the receiver side when the transmission has begun), you have to be creative here and make a lot a tests with a lot of phones before you can derive an actual detection threshold that works on all, notice that this might also be distance dependent

If you are unfamiliar with these subjects I would recommend a couple of great books:

Digital Modulation Techniques from Fuqin Xiong

DIGITAL COMMUNICATIONS Fundamentals and Applications from BERNARD SKLAR

Digital Communications from John G. Proakis

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck with a library I created for sound-based modems, [libquiet](https://github.com/quiet/quiet). It gives you a handful of profiles to work from, including a slow "Ultrasonic whisper" profile with spectral content above 19kHz. The library is written in C but would require some work to interface with iOS.